# C++11: erase-remove idiom when searching a specific member of object within a vector

Tags: c++11, erase

I know erase-remove can be used to remove elements matching a certain value, like this:

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), value), v.end());
```

However, if my vector has objects and I need to remove only those where one of its variables matches a specific value, is that possible with erase-remove?
So far, I've been using:

```
auto i = vect.begin();
while (i!=vect.end())
   if ((*i).field==someValue)
        i=vect.erase(i);
   else
      ++i;
```

Is there a way to do the same with erase-remove, or would this while loop be the right choice?

Comment: [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard algorithm [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) rather than `std::remove`.

Comment: I see! And would that be safer or better than my while loop, or I can use one or the other based just on my own preference? Thanks.

Comment: In general using the standard algorithm is a bit clearer than manual code. For example, in your code you are modifying the `vector` while iterating on it; that will cause problems at runtime. The standard algorithms already can handle this and other "common" issues, so it's better to use them as much as possible.

Comment: The original while loop is correct. However the main downside is that each time an element is removed, all the following elements in the vector are shifted (which takes `std::distance(it_to_removed_element, end)` moves). However, the `std::remove_if`/`std::remove` uses clever swaps to avoid unnecessary moves.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid writing erase-remove directly, mainly because really bad things happen if you miss the `container.end()` at the end.

```
template<class C, class T>
void erase_remove( C& c, T&& t ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<T>(t));
  c.erase(it, end(c));
}
template<class C, class F>
void erase_remove_if( C& c, F&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto it = std::remove_if(begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f));
  c.erase(it, end(c));
}
```

Then pass a lambda that tests the member variable for the `f` argument to `erase_remove_if`.